# Proper way to initialize a std::array from a C array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, initialization, copy

I'm getting an array from a C API, and I'd like to copy this to a std::array for further use in my C++ code. So what is the proper way of doing that ?

I 2 uses for this, one is:

```
struct Foo f; //struct from C api that has a uint8_t kasme[32] (and other things)

c_api_function(&f);
std::array<uint8_t, 32> a;
memcpy((void*)a.data(), f.kasme, a.size());
```

And this

```
class MyClass {
  std::array<uint8_t, 32> kasme;
  int type;
public:
  MyClass(int type_, uint8_t *kasme_) : type(type_)
  {
      memcpy((void*)kasme.data(), kasme_, kasme.size());
  }
  ...
}
...
MyClass k(kAlg1Type, f.kasme);
```

But this feels rather clunky. Is there an idiomatic way of doing this, that presumably doesn't involve memcpy ? For MyClass` perhaps I'm better off with 
the constructor taking a std::array that get moved into the member but I can't figure out the proper way of doing that either. ?

Comment: Why not `std::copy`?

Comment: except that it's not official yet: `auto x = std::to_array<uint8_t, 32>(cArrayPtr);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use algorithm `std::copy` declared in header `<algorithm>`. For example

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

//... 

struct Foo f; //struct from C api that has a uint8_t kasme[32] (and other things)

c_api_function(&f);
std::array<uint8_t, 32> a;
std::copy( f.kasme, f.kasme + a.size(), a.begin() );
```

If `f.kasme` is indeed an array then you can also write

```
std::copy( std::begin( f.kasme ), std::end( f.kasme ), a.begin() );
```

Comment: @binary01 It is my mistake.:) I deleted that part of the post.:)

Comment: This feels a bit risky. I'd let the number of characters that is being copied be determined by the target, instead of the source, to avoid array overflow. This can be done with `std::copy_n`: `std::copy_n(f.kasme, a.size(), a.begin());`